# In Django, how do I make my sessions persist through http://example.com and http://www.example.com?

Tags: python, django, apache, session

If I set a session in example.com, it doesn't work on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I'd like all subdomains, and all www, to be treated as one big thing.

example.com and all its subdomains should have all the session cookies of everything.

Do I change this in Apache2?

Comment: You should submit your solution as a separate answer, and then when possible, accept it. (You never know, though, a 'better' answer may come along.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".example.com"
```